# Empty data from a successful authentication using Windows.Security.Authentication

Tags: c#, azure, uwp

I am upgrading my app from windows 8.1 to windows 10 UWP.  Previously  I was using the Windows.Live API to obtain information about the user including a token that I would pass to the MobileService.LoginAsync Method.  This all had to be scrapped in favor of using windows.security.authentication.  Unfortunately, after the use of the code below, a successfull SSO token request results in an object that is missing most of the data that I need.  For now, just getting a username would be nice, I can expand from there.  Here is the code that I am having issues with...breakpoint set at the end of the if statement reveals the empty account.username field.

```
string accessToken = "";
        WebAccountProvider wap = await WebAuthenticationCoreManager.FindAccountProviderAsync("https://login.microsoft.com", "consumers");
        WebTokenRequest wt = new WebTokenRequest(wap,"wl.signin", "none");
        WebAccount account;
        WebTokenRequestResult wtrr = await WebAuthenticationCoreManager.RequestTokenAsync(wt);


        if (wtrr.ResponseStatus == WebTokenRequestStatus.Success)

        {

            accessToken = wtrr.ResponseData[0].Token;


            account = wtrr.ResponseData[0].WebAccount;


            var properties = wtrr.ResponseData[0].Properties;

        }
```

Comment: Additionally...the token received from this response returns "unauthorized" when used with MobileService.LoginWithMicrosoftAccountAsync(accessToken)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For now, just getting a username would be nice.

If you want to get the user name with `WebAuthenticationCoreManager`. You can try with following code:

```
private async void GetMsaTokenAsync(WebAccountProviderCommand command)
{
    WebTokenRequest request = new WebTokenRequest(command.WebAccountProvider, "wl.basic");
    WebTokenRequestResult result = await WebAuthenticationCoreManager.RequestTokenAsync(request);

    if (result.ResponseStatus == WebTokenRequestStatus.Success)
    {
        string token = result.ResponseData[0].Token; 

        var restApi = new Uri(@"https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token=" + token);

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var infoResult = await client.GetAsync(restApi);
            string content = await infoResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(content);

            string username = jsonObject["name"].GetString();
        }
    }
}
```

Using `WebAccount.UserName` property may not get user's name. But once you have the access token, you can use it to call the Microsoft Live APIs to obtain basic information about the user. For more info, please see **[Use the token](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/web-account-manager#use-the-token)** in [Connect to identity providers with Web Account Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/web-account-manager).

> Additionally...the token received from this response returns "unauthorized" when used with MobileService.LoginWithMicrosoftAccountAsync(accessToken).

This is because the token you've got above is an **access token**. However, The [LoginWithMicrosoftAccountAsync method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.mobileserviceclientextensions.loginwithmicrosoftaccountasync(v=azure.10).aspx) needs an **authentication token**.

> **Parameters**
>
> *thisClient*
>
> > Type: [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.mobileserviceclient(v=azure.10).aspx)
> >     The client with which to login.
>
> *authenticationToken*
>
> > Type: [System.String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx)
> >     Live SDK session authentication token.

If you want to authenticates the user with Microsoft Account, you can use service-directed authentication by calling [LoginAsync method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn268341.aspx) like following:

```
var user = await MobileService.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount);
```

For more info, please see [Add authentication to the app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-users/#add-authentication).

Comment: Thanks for the help, the difference between tokens was what threw me, got it working.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to check values of `ResponseData[0].Properties` field? It contains multiple parameters returned by http response.

For example for a user signed in with *workplace or school account* (Office365) we can get following data:

```
[0]: {[UPN, <user principal name - user's email address>]}
[1]: {[DisplayName, <user's first name and last name>]}
[2]: {[TenantId, <tenant id>]}
[3]: {[PasswordExpiresOn, <no. of ticks from 1.01.1601 divided by 1 second>]}
[4]: {[PasswordChangeUrl, https://portal.microsoftonline.com/ChangePassword.aspx]}
[5]: {[FirstName, <user's first name>]}
[6]: {[TokenExpiresOn, <no. of ticks from 1.01.1601 divided by 1 second>]}
[7]: {[OID, <object identifier as guid>]}
[8]: {[Authority, https://login.microsoftonline.com/common]}
[9]: {[SignInName, <user's email address>]}
[10]: {[UserName, <user's email address>]}
[11]: {[UID, <unique identifier>]}
[12]: {[LastName, <user's last name>]}
```

As you can see, we are able to get DisplayName, FirstName, LastName, and email address of the user. I'm not sure if the same data can be obtain for personal accounts, but you can find it out easily - just convert `ResponseData[0].Properties` to list in Immediate Window:

```
ResponseData[0].Properties.ToList();
```

We can also get TokenExpiresOn value, so we can easily handle token refresh.

To get date of token expiration, multiply this value by 10 000 000 (no. of ticks in 1 second) and add 1600 years, e.g.:

```
var date = new DateTimeOffset(13129745922 * 10000000, new TimeSpan()).AddYears(1600);
date.LocalDateTime.ToString();  // Output: "24.01.2017 15:38:42"
```